# How to add category name to url path for an article in Joomla 4?

Tags: articles, url, category, joomla-4

How to display category name in the url path?

Say I have a category named `cat1`, and an `article1` under this category.
I want to display `website.wb/cat1/article1`, but what I get is `website.wb/article1`. As you can see, the category is missing…

What should I do to enable the category in the url?

PS: SEF and URL Rewriting are both enabled, categories are published.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Joomla core you need to setup a menu structure that will correspond to what you want to achieve with your URLs. Menus are important in Joomla.

From the example of the URLs in your question - it seems like you have created a menu item for the article1.

If you want all articles of that category (cat1) to be reachable under the cat1/article1,art2,art3 pattern, then create a category type menu item for the cat1 category. You can create that menu item in a hidden menu (a menu with no menu module) - or set the menu item itself as hidden (Menu Item -> Link Type tab -> Display in Menu).

If you want to have a menu item in your menu that will link directly to the cat1/article1, then make the menu item of the article a child of your cat1 menu item.

Alternatively, there are 3rd party SEF extensions that offer various different capabilities. Check in [**JED for SEF extensions**](https://extensions.joomla.org/category/site-management/sef/).

Comment: Thank you very much, your explanation is better than the one given in the Joomla doc… **But I get an unexpected behavior**, as it seems **I cannot set, at the same time, an article as category path**, like `cat1` holding article0… Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Just an added note, here. Unless I'm missing something, you don't need to hide the root menu item. If you only want the children to show up in your navigation, when you create the menu module for the navigation, tell it to start at level 2 of the menu -- it will then ignore the root level menu item.

Comment: for some informations, take a look at this: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/25032/how-to-set-a-root-article-as-subpath-url-for-children-articles